# Button height custom list view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to create a custom `listview` with 4 columns. Everything works fine, except for the height of each row, it's too big.

Here the result I have:

[image]

The problem comes from my button, because android take a weird height, that doesn't match the height of my image (I already check my image and it have the right proportion).

Here an example:

[image]

And I would like the "zone" of my image to just be the size of my image.

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAudioNom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:text="Audio 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAudioDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_weight="18" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="29">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgAudioNote"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_star"
            app:tint="@color/purple_500"
            android:contentDescription="@string/txt_content_desc"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAudioNote"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="29">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAudioPlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_play"
            app:tint="@color/purple_500"
            android:contentDescription="@string/txt_content_desc" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you have any idea on how I can change that, thank you

EDIT:

I found a solution, I needed to add this line of code to my ImageButton:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: Please don't add solutions into the question itself. It's alot harder to find this way. You are free to answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

Needed changes:

- `wrap_content` all the views.
- `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` the `txtAudioNote`

Extra:

- No need to the `RelativeLayout` at the bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAudioNom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Audio 1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAudioDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="18"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="29"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgAudioNote"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:src="@drawable/icon_star"
        android:contentDescription="@string/txt_content_desc"
            app:tint="@color/purple_500" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAudioNote"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAudioPlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="29"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:contentDescription="@string/txt_content_desc" 
        android:src="@drawable/icon_play"
        app:tint="@color/purple_500" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for you answer
But it haven't change the final result, the only thing that have change is in the preview, my button are on top of the screen. I think the problem come from scaleType

Comment: Probably `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` can solve it.. Is `icon_play` image a vector drawable or png?

Comment: I found the solution, I just had to add the line : android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Answer (score 0):

He has found a solution which he states in the EDIT:

```xml
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

But I want to add for those who want to do it programmatically.

```dart
//add in onCreate
view.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```